# start the value of input in decimal's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using the IMaskInput from 'react-imask' but i don't know how i can start the value on decimals, like when the user put the value start on 0,01, and as he will putting more number it will be like this:
0,01, 0,15, 1,50, 15,00, 150,00

I try this but not work

```
<InputTextContentMask
  {...inputProps}
  mask={'num'}
  lazy={false}
  blocks={{
     num: {
        mask: Number,
        scale: 2, 
        signed: false,
        thousandsSeparator: '.',
        padFractional: true, 
        normalizeZeros: true,
        },
  }}
  onBlur={forceOnChange}
  unmask={true}
/>
```

Comment: You've specified a thousands separator. Is there a similar property for decimal character? perhaps `radix: ','`

Comment: Alos, _"I try this but not work"_ is not a good description of the problem. Please include details of what you've tried what you're inputting and the results.

Comment: In addition to details about what happens with you "I try this" version, can you add the original version of the code? (before you tried to solve your problem)